# C++ set Windows time from ms since 1/1/1970

Tags: c++, time

Good day. I have a time in ms since 1/1/1970, e.g. 1487520625361

So, i need to set Windows time from it. I found a SetLocalTime(&SYSTEMTIME) function. So, i need to parse number of ms, or it can be performed more easily?

Comment: Is the time you have local or UTC?

Comment: @MatteoItalia UTC, but it's doesn't matter that time on PC will be in UTC

Comment: Convert to `FILETIME` first (basic algebra), and then to `SYSTEMTIME` (using the `FileTimeToSystemTime` function).

Comment: @RaymondChen yep, below placed answer, but thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you never want to work with the `SYSTEMTIME` structure (which is already split down and useful just for display), but with `FILETIME` (time expressed as number of 100 ns intervals since 1/1/1601) and convert just at the end of your calculations.

So you need to:

- convert your ms since 1/1/1970 to 100ns since 1/1/1601;
- put the result into a `FILETIME`;
- convert the `FILETIME` to `SYSTEMTIME`;
- call `SetLocalTime` (if the original timestamp was in local time) or `SetSystemTime` (if it was in UTC).

The most boring step is the first one, since you have to calculate the difference between the two Epochs; fortunately, it has already been done in [KB167296](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167296/how-to-convert-a-unix-time-t-to-a-win32-filetime-or-systemtime), and it turns out that the number we are after is 116444736000000000.

So:

```
void msecSinceEpochToFileTime(uint64_t msecSinceEpoch, FILETIME *ft) {
    uint64_t result = msecSinceEpoch * 10000; // ms => 100ns
    result += 116444736000000000ULL;    // Unix epoch in FILETIME
    ft->dwLowDateTime = (DWORD) result;
    ft->dwHighDateTime = result >> 32;
}
```

Then converting `FILETIME` to `SYSTEMTIME` is just a matter of calling [FileTimeToSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280(v=vs.85).aspx).